# Userform combobox where i can add or remove items based on cell color coding

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm trying to code a ComboBox in to a userform, that takes it's items from existing list. The list has color coded cells in the colors of red and green, I would like to add and remove items from the ComboBox based on color coding, red would mean it appears on the list and green means it won't appear. So far i haven't found any sollutions for it.

[image: Color coding]

I would appreciate your help

Comment: Tell us what you've tried and what problems you had. You need to add an If statement to check the cell colour before adding to the combobox list.

Comment: Adding code will improve the chances of answering your questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to check column C (column = 3):

```
Dim i as integer

For i = 1 to 50 'row 1 to 50
    If Cells(i,3).Interior.Color = RGB(insert RGB of red color) Then 'So if the statement is true, we want to add the cell's contents to the ComboBox.

        YourSheetName.YourComboBoxName.AddItem Cells(i,2).Value 'Add cell contents to the ComboBox

    End If
Next i
```

I believe that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that we have:

- A userform named frmTest
- A combobox named cmbTest

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

      Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

          Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

          frmTest.cmbTest.Clear

          For i = 1 To Lastrow
              If .Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 255 Then

                  With frmTest.cmbTest
                      .AddItem (Sheet1.Range("A" & i))
                  End With

              End If

          Next i

      End With

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this one.